# Data is added in front end every time the page is refreshed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC with a simple form which reads data from a file and shows the data in the form in browser.The issue is that every time I refresh the browser,the data from the file is added again in the front end.This is the controller where I have the issue:

```
public ActionResult Main(BankingModel _bm)
 {           
            ViewBag.List = IO.Read();
            return View(_bm);
 }
```

IO.Read reads the data from the file,stores it in the Viewbag and send it to the view.But the controller is called every time I refresh the page and the data from the browser remains,resulting in duplicated values.Is there a way,when I refresh thee browser,to also refresh the front end view data from the form?

Comment: You can just call `ViewData.Clear();` in your Controller method since `ViewBag` uses it internally.

Comment: I tryed using ViewData.Clear() before  ViewBag.List = IO.Read(); command and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you show me your `View` code? You are sending a BankingModel type to your View with a ViewBag. I would like to see how you are displaying it. Otherwise I would suggest you to use `TempData["List"]=IO.Read();` Because ViewBag maintains data on refresh also but TempData dispose after rendered once.

Comment: I tried with TempData and it didn't worked.Here is the view:  https://pastebin.com/xPTQFEkA

Comment: Before your return your `View()` in the controller, do a `ModelState.Clear()`.If you are using `POST` to submit your form, then please stop returning `View()`. Use PRG instead and redirect to a GET if the action is a success: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I tried Model.Clear and it still didn't worked.I will try to use PRG.Thanks.

Comment: Show code of `IO.Read()` and the `.cshtml` code. The ASP code is correct.

Comment: This is the IO.Read code : https://pastebin.com/7a7F5jUg
The .cshtml code is posted above in the pastebin link.

Comment: @WorkoutChannel Initialize a new instance of your list inside the `Read` method: `public static List<BankingModel> lst = new List<BankingModel>();`

Comment: I realized what the problem was.The IO.Read() function had a list which was initialized outside of the function.So every time I refreshed the page,the function added new data in the list.While the session is alive,the list did not reset.I initialized the list in the function and now I do not have any duplicates in the form.Also,the ViewData.Clear() works.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks Rahul,I also realized this was the issue while you were typing the response :).Maybe you can add this as an answer so I can marked it as correct :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your particular case, you were not intiailzing a new instance of your `List<BankingModel>` which caused the data to be appended to the list always. The solution to this would be to initialize a new instance of your list inside the `Read` method:

`public static List<BankingModel> lst = new List<BankingModel>()`

And in order to clear your `ViewBag` since `ViewBag` maintains data on refresh, you can just call `ViewData.Clear();` in your Controller method since `ViewBag` uses it internally.